# Get an array of meta_values for a user meta_key

Tags: wpdb, user-meta, meta-value

I need to get an array of all the meta_values for a user meta_key. I found this code:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'my_cities_meta_key'" );
```

which results in this:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "Chicago" [1]=> string(8) "New York" [2]=> string(8) "New York" }
```

This is not exactly what I need. See how New York value is listed twice because there are two users located in New York? I need an array that lists each unique meta_value once. Like this:

```
$cities = array(New York, Chicago, Los Angeles);
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a `DISTINCT` to your SQL query, something like:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT(meta_value) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'my_cities_meta_key'" );
```

Alternatively, if you want to do it with php for some reason (if you want to know that a city is listed twice before displaying only unique entries)

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'my_cities_meta_key'" );
$cities = array_keys(array_flip($cities));
```

If you want to filter based on user role using only SQL, something like this should work, though it's a little hacky because WP stores user roles in a serialized array:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Distinct(c.meta_value) 
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta AS r 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS c
      ON r.user_id = c.user_id
    WHERE r.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
    AND c.meta_key = 'my_cities_meta_key'");
```

To add filters based on multiple meta keys you do more `INNER JOIN`, e.g. for your region metakey:

```
$cities = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Distinct(c.meta_value) 
    FROM $wpdb->usermeta AS r 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS c
      ON r.user_id = c.user_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS re
      ON r.user_id = re.user_id
    WHERE r.meta_value LIKE '%subscriber%'
    AND c.meta_key = 'my_cities_meta_key'
    AND re.meta_key = 'region'");
```

Comment: Ah ha! I didn't know about DISTINCT. That solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, do you know how I could revise the query to add an additional qualifier that says the user "role" must be "subscriber"? So basically, only pull values from the meta_key "my_cities_meta_key" if the users who have this key/value are subscribers. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've added it to the response.  Let me know if you need clarification on the anatomy of the query.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I think I understand, though I'm not sure I totally getting what's happening here: `INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta AS c ON r.user_id` Would you mind explaining that in non-sql speak?

Comment: Since we are interested in 2 values (role/city) that are both in the usermeta table we have to join that table to itself but lookup a different meta key.  I called the city lookup "c" and the role lookup "r", you do the role lookup first since that is the exclusionary call.  So the plain language way to say this is "Select the ids of the users who have the role subscriber, then look up the distinct city names of those users with those ids."

Comment: Thank you. That explanation makes sense. But I'm embarrassed to admit I'm still not able to figure out how to add yet another condition to the query. I need to add an additional rule that will say "Select the IDs of the users who have the role subscriber, AND who have a meta_value of "2" for the meta_key of "region" - then look up the distinct city names of those users." I tried adding another AND statement, but it broke it. Also, in general - is a SQL query the most efficient way to do this? Just want to make sure I'm not making it harder than it needs to be. (Thanks for your continued help).

Comment: You need an `INNER JOIN` for each meta key before you can add the additional condition.  See my edit.

Comment: Ah ha! I get it now. Seeing the third condition helped me see the pattern. Thanks for sticking with me!